# Dynamically setting sourceSets in a gradle plugin

Tags: gradle

I have written a plugin that generates java classes based on some metadata in another file type. We currently have an in-house Ant task that does this and I am just calling that Ant task from Gradle to do the conversion.

However what I want to be able to do in my plugin is manipulate the projects sourceSets to add the destination directory. How do I access the sourceSets of a project from within the plugin?

e.g. Let's say the metadata was an xsd that I run through the xjc ant task (it is not but this is similar). I specify the output directory as an ext property on the project and I dont want to also have to add this same value to the sourceSet, I want the plugin to insert it for me so the compile step will automatically include the generated code.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The plugin gets passed the project in its `apply` method. From there the procedure is very similar to a build script, e.g. `project.apply plugin: "java"; project.sourceSets { ... }`. Note that the concept of source sets is added by the Java (base) plugin, so you have to apply that first.

Comment: Thanks, I am sure I tried something like this and it didnt work, but as it now works I must have just thought I tried it.